# Issue with version of protobuf in google sheets api

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, pip, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run the line 'pip install google-api-python-client' however I am receiving an error that my protobuf is version 4.12.12 but that it is not compatible. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install --upgrade protobuf==3.20.3`. 3.20.3 is the most recently-published version that will satisfy the requirements of the other libraries and also isn't a beta/release candidate. You can always check the releases on the package index under the [history tab](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/#history).